# What happens to clan, disciplines, blood and curse after losing the struggle after diablerie?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade, diablerie

In my campaign an old Giovanni Kindred caught an even older and much stronger Cappadocian by surprise and diablerized her. He almost immediately lost the struggle of souls and she took over control. Now that this very old Cappadocian, a Childe of Japeth, has taken over the body of this Giovanni, I am left wondering what happens in terms of clan, disciplines, blood and curse?

It is often stated that the curse is linked to the Kindred's soul, so it would make sense that she has the Cappadocian curse. It also makes sense she keeps her mental disciplines, but some are physical and might not transfer from either kindred to the other... As far as blood and clan go, the Giovanni found their origin within the Cappadocian clan anyway so I'm leaning towards her identifying as Cappadocian by blood.

My players are somewhat divided with the main argument being that (as far as we're aware) there is no canon lore on the matter. Has anybody been in this situation or does anyone know how to resolve this based on the (V20) books?

Comment: Would be good if you specified the edition, it seems like V20 changed the rules of the Amaranth. A friend of mine told that *The Black Hand: A Guide to the Tal’Mahe’Ra* has the new rules.

Comment: @Baskakov_Dmitriy We use V20 for rules and lore but intermixed with a lot of fluff from the older books. I'm looking for any existing examples in either V20 or older VTM books, no VTR though.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The best canonical example is that of Montgomery "Monty" Coven, who committed diablerie on Mithras, the prince of London, and was lost in the process. You can find his story in ***Children of the Night***. There, you'll see that he retained his clan (Assamite *antitribu*) and related curse, but gained a frightful number of dots in disciplines (both mental and physical) along with his new, lower Generation. The mind of Mithras retains control, but elements of Coven still manifest now and again.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds perfect! I'll see if I can get my hands on a copy.